# How to get nvidia drivers for GeForce GT635?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, download, nvidia-geforce

I'm trying to download drivers for my GeForce GT635 2GB, but when I go to http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us it doesn't list any GT635. It lists the GT630 and GT640, though. I tried auto-detecting, but it doesn't seems to work. What should I do?

Comment: The best method.  Install the current driver the OEM provides.  This a desktop or laptop?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this post](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/673226/what-driver-for-gt-635-card-/) you can use the same drivers as GT630, I would try installing those. My experience is that the driver installer checks if the installed hardware is supported before installing.